# Windows 8 computer name with special character

Tags: windows-8

When installing windows 8 on my laptop I created user with special char `š` so it looks like `C:\Users\Dušan` so now I have huge problems when trying to use some software like VirtualBox:
[image]

and this is not the only one for example I cant change my wamp www root folder to anything that is on my desktop ( because it contains `š` in url ) ...

But when I try to change computer name default computer name is `Dusan` so I have no idea how to deal with this issue exept reinstalling system (what will be my last option).

Anyone have any idea how to change this name?

Comment: I know this is still a pain, but much less so that doing a full reinstall: try creating a new user and copying the contents of the old home folder. I'm not sure what you meant by the "default computer name".

Comment: By default computer name I mean name that I need to change, but that name is good, it doesnt contain char that makes problem for me

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean your username, not computer name. Unfortunately there's no Microsoft-recommended method of renaming user directories. Renaming an account doesn't affect user directory's name to avoid breaking absolute paths.

The easiest solution I can think of (but I haven't tested it) is to create a new user account. Then you can try to boot some LiveCD distro of Linux, delete the new account's folder and replace it with a copy of the first one (effectively substituting new account folder with the old one). Try if everything works as expected. In case of any problems you can delete following directories:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
```

(you can also delete other Microsoft-related folders in `Local`, `LocalLow` and `Roaming`). Windows should recreate them when needed. Be careful to work on the new copy, not original user directory.

I have also googled some [user directory renaming guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html), but I haven't tested it too. It may provide better result, but it's a serious registry modification and you can break something, so make full system backup before trying. My method looks safer to me.

Comment: I think backing up everything is a good start here for sure. I will test your metod and get back to you as soon as posible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a user on Windows 7 with the special character `ń`.

The only problem is in the folder name, not in the username itself.

So, my solution to the problem:

- Create a completely new user, with no special characters in it.
  Windows will create a new folder for this user, with no special
  character in the name.
- Move your files from your previous user folder with the special
  characters to the new user folder without special characters.
- Log out from your old user and log in to the new user.
- Delete your old user through Windows Control Panel, *do not just delete the folder*. (Make sure here that you really moved all your
  important files).
- Still in the user Control Panel, rename your user name to have the
  special characters. *This will not rename the folder*, but only the
  system user name string of your user.

In the end you should have a user in a folder without special characters, but in every screen that it shows your name, including the Windows login screen, the special characters will be shown.